# Error when including sourceCpp in Rscript

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to include my cpp file into an Rscript using

```
library(Rcpp)
Rcpp::sourceCpp('Simulation/Code/RcppFuncs.cpp')
```

However, I get the following error. Is there something that I've forgotten? The file is definitely in the folder, unlike the error suggests.

```
Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp(file = "Simulation/Code/RcppFuncs.cpp") : 
      file not found: 'Simulation/Code/RcppFuncs.cpp'
    In addition: Warning messages:
    1: In normalizePath(dirname(file)) :
      path[1]="Simulation/Code": No such file or directory
    2: In normalizePath(file, winslash = "/") :
      path[1]="Simulation/Code/RcppFuncs.cpp": No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you tried using the whole path as in `c:/somthing/something`

Comment: What’s the R working directory? The argument to  `sourceCpp` has to be either an absolute path or a relative path starting at the working directory.

Comment: Here is the chorus from a song I frequently sing here: _build a package_.  It removes, among many other things, all headaches about paths.

Comment: @RalfStubner Jrakru56, the working directory exists in a remote server that I ssh into. I tried the full and relative paths and it says "file not found". I may have to install something to talk with the remote server

Comment: Have you copied the cpp file to the remote server? You have to use paths as they exist on the remote machine!

Comment: Yes, the cpp and Rscript files are in the same folder and I am using the path of the remote machine. In the end, I think Dirk's solution is the best. Another option was to include the functions with cppFunction in the Rscript.